# Empty fields after joining attributes by location to join point to polygon layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, table

I'm trying to join a point layer to a polygon layer to get a specific field in the attribute table into the polygon layer. I want the polygon layer "Zone" to have the field "Improved" from the point layer "Permits". Is there a way to join based on location? All the points in "Permits" are located within the respective polygons in "zone". I've tried performing a Join Attributes by location" but the fields in the new layer end up being blank.

Comment: `Join attributes by location` seems to be the right tool. Can you describe your point layer "Permits"? One possibility is the "Permits" does not have any numerical fields.  (If "Improved" field is string (text), it will be left-aligned on the attribute table.)

Comment: The permits does have quite a few numerical fields with several site ID fields and an object ID field. I'm choosing the "within" geometric predicate, is this correct? Does it join any point within each polygon?

Comment: If you set Target layer = polygon and Join layer = points (as @mapperx's  good instruction), you will not be able to choose "within" predicate.

Comment: @Aurust you need to try out each of Geographic predicate to get the right one, (I can remember the right one). Try each of the options and lets know what you get. In case you still need assistance, would check it for you.

Comment: I'm making a bit more progress but still am not getting what I want. Now I get about 15 entries with fields that are filled in even though I know there should be hundreds of entries. Each zone should have an entry.

Comment: Could you make a clip of the screen to show it? Also are there multiple points on a single polygon?

Comment: In QGIS 3.4 you can download the Nearest Neighbor join plugin. I kept getting blanks, but the plugin gave me the result I was after.

Comment: I am facing with the same problem, after join two layers (spatial or attribute join) the output layer shown the fields of the joined layer, but not values within... So the tool perform propertly the join action, but not populate the valeues in the cells...
I have to say that the problem is only when I try to include the join tool within a QGIS model...

Answer (score 3):

To join attribute from one layer to another you can click the ***Join attribute by location*** tool under the Vector tab. This will open the tool screen. Choose the Target layer which is the one you want to add data to ie **Zone** and the Join layer which is the layer with data you want to transfer **Permits**. Depending on the version of qgis you use it might be slightly different. I am running QGIS 2.18.3. Then you need to choose a Geometric predicate (not sure the exact option) you can try out one of the different options from **intersect, touches, overlap or crosses**. And then choose the take attribute of first located feature. Check and choose any other appropriate options form the menu and save to choice location

[image: Screenshot]